# Reactjs, how to construct a specific json to add amount between per month

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have this data from my API: dataN

[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

for more details inside each: {...}

```
{
 date: "2018-01-01"
 import: 1

},
{
 date: "2018-03-03"
 import: "10"

},
{
 date: "2018-03-20"
 import: 10

},
{
 date: "2020-05-01"
 import: 10

},
{
 date: "2020-05-02"
 import: 10

},
{
 date: "2020-05-03"
 import: 10

},
```

I have a function working that is extracting all month found and year as a result like this one:

Array:
["2018-01", "2018-03", "2020-05", .....]

Using this array I have another function (working) that seek between date  and is giving me how many operations was made betewen the give date.

Example: in year and month: 2018-01
I have only 1 operation and the result will be:

```
{
 date: "2018-01-01"
 import: 1

},
```

Same thing with for example:"2020-05"
I have 3 operations so the result will be:
    {
     date: "2020-05-01"
     import: 10

```
},
{
 date: "2020-05-02"
 import: 10

},
{
 date: "2020-05-03"
 import: 10

},
```

Now that I have the operations carried out every month and ordered by year I want to add the amount to carry out in that month.

My objective is for each month and year add all amount  (It´s alway a number)
(Have a Total amount for each month)
Example for:

"2018-01"  import
"2018-03"  import of date 2020-03-03 + import of date 2020-03-20
"2018-05"  import of date 2020-05-01 + import of date 2020-05-01 + import of date: "2020-05-03

final json:

```
{
date : "2018-01"
import : 1
},
{
date : "2018-03"
import : 20
},
{
date : "2018-05"
import : 30
}
```

I have this code, but I realy don´t know to obtain as needed:

I realy apresiate any help.

```
//["2018-01", "2018-02", "2018-03", "2018-04", "2018-05", .....]
        var Total = 0;
        array.forEach(function(item){
            //console.log(item)
            var a = moment(item);
            var start = a.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            var b = a.add(30, 'days');
            var end = b.format('YYYY-MM-DD')


            console.log("procesing search between date : ",start , " and last date: ", end)
            DataFromApi.forEach((value, key) => {

                var EntreFechas = moment(value.compra_fecha_oper).isBetween(String(start), String(end) ); // true
                if ( EntreFechas === true && value.estado == "Finalizado" && value.moneda_crypto == TipoCrypto ){
                    console.log(key, " Value Date: ",value.compra_fecha_oper ,"Has result: ",  EntreFechas)

                    if (value.estado == "Finalizado" && value.moneda_crypto == TipoCrypto){

                        var jsonObjFinalizadas = 
                        { 
                        "fecha": value.compra_fecha_oper,
                        "importe":Total += parseFloat(value.compra_en_fiat),
                        }



                        ArrayFechasImportes.push(jsonObjFinalizadas)


                       }




                }

            });

          });

          console.log("El payaso: ",ArrayFechasImportes )
```

Complet code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import moment from "moment";

class RentabilidadMensual extends Component {


    //Se calcculará la rentablidad mensual obtenida.

    constructor (props){
        super(props)



          this.state ={

        }
    }


    render() {

        const DataFromApi = this.props.data;
        console.log("Datos de la API", this.props.data)
        var TipoCrypto = this.props.selectedcrypto;
        var DatosFechas = [];
        var ArrayFechasImportes = [];

        //del objeto se extrae las fechas del key: compra_fecha_oper y se genera un array: DatosFechas
        this.props.data.forEach((value, key) => {
            console.log("1-key =>", key, "1-value =>", value.compra_fecha_oper);

            DatosFechas.push(value.compra_fecha_oper)
            })

        console.log("Busco", DatosFechas)
         // Obtengo todas las fechas de la API: ["2020-04-29", "2020-04-19", ...]



        const getFirstAndLastDate = (DatosFechas) => {
            DatosFechas = DatosFechas.sort()
            //Devuelve primera fecha y última fecha
            return [DatosFechas[0], DatosFechas[DatosFechas.length - 1]]
          }

          console.log("First Date: ", getFirstAndLastDate(DatosFechas)[0], "Last Date: ", getFirstAndLastDate(DatosFechas)[1])



        function ListarLosMesesEntreDosFechas(inicio, fin) {

            var dateStart = moment(inicio);
            var dateEnd = moment(fin);
            var interim = dateStart.clone();
            var timeValues = [];

            while (dateEnd > interim || interim.format('M') === dateEnd.format('M')) {
               timeValues.push(interim.format('YYYY-MM'));
               interim.add(1,'month');
            }
            return timeValues
        }
        console.log("Valor de ListarLosMesesEntreDosFechas:", ListarLosMesesEntreDosFechas(getFirstAndLastDate(DatosFechas)[0], getFirstAndLastDate(DatosFechas)[1]) )

        //Para cada elemento del array con el datos de Año-mes se busca activiades en este mes y se suma.

        var array = ListarLosMesesEntreDosFechas(getFirstAndLastDate(DatosFechas)[0], getFirstAndLastDate(DatosFechas)[1])

        //["2018-01", "2018-02", "2018-03", "2018-04", "2018-05", .....]
        var Total = 0;
        array.forEach(function(item){
            //console.log(item)
            var a = moment(item);
            var start = a.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            var b = a.add(30, 'days');
            var end = b.format('YYYY-MM-DD')


            console.log("procesing search between date : ",start , " and last date: ", end)
            DataFromApi.forEach((value, key) => {

                var EntreFechas = moment(value.compra_fecha_oper).isBetween(String(start), String(end) ); // true
                if ( EntreFechas === true && value.estado == "Finalizado" && value.moneda_crypto == TipoCrypto ){
                    console.log(key, " Value Date: ",value.compra_fecha_oper ,"Has result: ",  EntreFechas)

                    if (value.estado == "Finalizado" && value.moneda_crypto == TipoCrypto){

                        var jsonObjFinalizadas = 
                        { 
                        "fecha": value.compra_fecha_oper,
                        "importe":Total += parseFloat(value.compra_en_fiat),
                        }



                        ArrayFechasImportes.push(jsonObjFinalizadas)


                       }




                }

            });

          });

          console.log("El payaso: ",ArrayFechasImportes )



        return (
            <div>
                test...

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default RentabilidadMensual;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done one requirement as below. Please try this example and implement other.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class JsonExample extends Component {

    state = {
        updatedJson: []
    };

    json = [
        {date: "2018-01-01", import: "XXX <--number"},
        {date: "2018-03-03", import: "XXX<--number"},
        {date: "2018-03-20", import: "XXX<--number"},
        {date: "2018-03-25", import: "XXX<--number"},
        {date: "2020-05-01", import: "XXX<--number"},
        {date: "2020-05-02", import: "XXX<--number"},
        {date: "2020-05-03", import: "XXX<--number"},
    ];

    componentDidMount() {
        let updatedJson = [];
        this.json.map(value => {
            let d = new Date(value.date);
            let yearMonth = ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + d.getFullYear();
            updatedJson.push(yearMonth);
        });
        this.setState({updatedJson: updatedJson});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {JSON.stringify(this.state.updatedJson)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Updated full code based on the requirement**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class JsonExample extends Component {

    state = {
        monthlyData: [],
        sortedData: [],
        monthlyTotalImport: []
    };

    json = [
        {date: "2018-01-01", import: 7},
        {date: "2018-01-21", import: 1},
        {date: "2018-03-03", import: 10},
        {date: "2018-03-20", import: 10},
        {date: "2020-05-01", import: 10},
        {date: "2017-12-01", import: 5},
        {date: "2020-05-02", import: 10},
        {date: "2020-05-03", import: 10},
    ];

    componentDidMount() {
        let data = [];
        this.json.map(value => {
            let d = new Date(value.date);
            data.push({...value, date2: d});
        });

        let sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => a.date2 - b.date2);
        console.log(sortedData, 'sorted');

        let monthlyData = [];
        sortedData.map(value => {
            let d = new Date(value.date);
            let yearMonth = ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + d.getFullYear();
            monthlyData.push({...value, yearMonth: yearMonth});
        });
        console.log(monthlyData, 'monthly data');

        let result = monthlyData.reduce((acc, item) => ({
            ...acc,
            [item.yearMonth]: (acc[item.yearMonth] || 0) + item.import
        }), {});
        this.setState({monthlyTotalImport: result});
        console.log(result, 'result');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {JSON.stringify(this.state.monthlyTotalImport)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I will try.

Comment: Thk for you help, I already have a function that is doing the same thing you are proposing.  The point that I am locked in at the end where I have to add the amounts by date and by year.

Comment: I
To avoid confusion I will add the desired final json at the beginning of this post.

Comment: @Kentron.dna, I have added another example that meets your requirement 100%. Please check it

Comment: OK, lets me try. I will give you an answer and thank you very much!

Comment: It works perfectly, you don't know how grateful I am. I was trying to fix this problem for several days.

Comment: @Kentron.dna, It is pleasure that I could help you :)